# Best way to read xml from API, parse the xml and load into database

Tags: java, xml, api, hibernate, jaxb

We have a integration requirement where we have to read the xml response from the API request and then parse the xml and insert them into the table. Proposal is to use Java.

Proposal is to use Java. But I'm very new to JAVA and APIs as my background is mainly on the database and SQL. Based on the requirement i have done my research from past 3 days and came up with the below solution.

I have divided this into 3 parts

1. Reading the XML : Use **Java/Spring** to read the API xml response
2. Parsing the XML : Use **JAXB** to parse the xml and get the needed fields
3. Loading them into the database : Use **Hibernate** to load it into the database

Please suggest if this will work or are there any better ways? Please let me know if this is not the right forum to ask this question i will then delete my post. I'm not looking for any code but just the architectural point of view of how we can go ahead here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your choice. But since Java is new to you, you might want to try to keep the use of big, heavy frameworks to a minimum. If this is a simple client you can omit the Spring part and use pure Java. And if you only have to fill one table then plain JDBC may be sufficient.

Comment: @vanje Great. Thanks for your valuable inputs. We will definitely consider them :)